# Spring Cloud Sleuth is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-sleuth

You can check the Sleuth 3.1 Migration Guide over here [https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide].
If you want to disable this check, just set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]']]
2023-12-15T15:11:43.043+05:30  WARN 10324 --- [           main] z.r.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter   : Timed out waiting for in-flight spans to send
2023-12-15T15:11:43.096+05:30  INFO 10324 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-12-15T15:11:43.141+05:30 ERROR 10324 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to following reasons:

- Spring Cloud Sleuth is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train

Action:

Consider applying the following actions:

- Migrate from Spring Cloud Sleuth to Micrometer Tracing .
  You can check the Sleuth 3.1 Migration Guide over here [https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide].
  If you want to disable this check, just set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]

Process finished with exit code 1

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

spring cloud and parent dependency versoion is spring parent 3.1.6 and the spring cloud version is 2022.0.4